# Using Common Lisp for new Machine Learning project

Tags: machine-learning, common-lisp

We've been looking into languages for a ML project at work. A colleague of mine is a big Common Lisp fan, however I have some concerns. Are there any good/modern ML libraries for Common Lisp that people know of (something comparable to Weka)? Also, does anyone know of a *good* statistics library for CLisp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [ABCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/) you can use Weka in your Common Lisp program.

There are some libraries indexed on [cliki](http://www.cliki.net/statistics) [RCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/rcl/), [RCLG](https://github.com/blindglobe/rclg) and [cl-random](https://github.com/tpapp/cl-random/) in particular look interesting.

Answer (score 0):

[GSLL](http://common-lisp.net/project/gsll/) gives you access to [GSL's](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) statistics functions.